# How do I get TypeScript lookup types to work in this situation?

Tags: typescript, generics, lookup, mapped-types

Sorry for the unmotivated title, but I really have no clue what else to call it.

I have an enum, and I want to match each of the enum's entries to a type. I'm doing this so that parameters of functions can change dynamically based on the first parameter. An example:

```js
enum Enum {
    A,
    B,
    C
}

interface TypeMap {
    [Enum.A]: number,
    [Enum.B]: string,
    [Enum.C]: boolean
}

function doSomething<K extends Enum>(a: K, b: TypeMap[K]) {
    //
}
```

The type system works correctly when **calling** `doSomething`, for example: `doSomething(Enum.A, 5)` works, but `doSomething(Enum.A, "hello")` doesn't. However, what I can't get to work is this:

```js
function doSomething<K extends Enum>(a: K, b: TypeMap[K]) {
    if (a === Enum.A) {
        let num: number = b;
    }
}
```

Typescript errors out at the assignment to `num`, but clearly, CLEARLY, it should work. If `a` is `Enum.A`, then `b` has to BY DEFINITION be `number`, right? What am I doing wrong? How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here is that control flow analysis only works to narrow the types of *values* of union type.  It does not result in the narrowing of *generic type parameters* that extend union types.  Just because you've tested `a`, of type `K extends Enum`, it *doesn't* narrow `K` itself.  There's an open issue in GitHub about this: [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085).

One problem with narrowing `K` when checking `a` is that nothing stops `K` from being the full union type `Enum`.  For example:

```
function getEnum(): Enum { return Enum.A };
```

If I call `getEnum()` I will definitely get `Enum.A` at runtime, but the compiler only sees the return type as `Enum`, the full union type.  And therefore if you call `doSomething()`, the compiler allows this:

```
doSomething(getEnum(), "oops"); // no error!
```

Oops. So in fact the error in the implementation of `doSomething()` is actually warning you of a real (if uncommon) issue: `K` could be `Enum`, `a` could be `Enum.A`, and `b` could be something other than `number`.

If you could tell the compiler that `K` is restricted to being *exactly one member* of the `Enum` union, then it would be safer to do the narrowing.  Right now there's no way to express that sort of generic constraint, but there's an open issue asking for it: [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808).

For now then you'll have to work around this by giving up some compiler-guaranteed type safety, such as using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```
function doSomethingAssert<K extends Enum>(a: K, b: TypeMap[K]) {
  if (a === Enum.A) {
    let num = b as number; // assert here
  } else if (a === Enum.B) {
    let str = b as string; // assert here
  } 
}
```

This is probably the least disruptive solution for you.  You could other workarounds like the user defined type guard in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855419/2887218), but it has the same lack of type safety (nothing prevents you from writing `let num = b as string`, and nothing prevents you from writing `isA(a, "oops")` in the type guard.  So it's up to you which flavor of unsoundness you like better.

---

One last idea: maybe you'd consider refactoring your data to use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) instead of a pair of function parameters?  And have it no longer generic?  The compiler is much better about using control flow analysis on discriminated union objects.  So you'd package `a` and `b` into a single object type, like this:

```
type DiscrimUnion = { [K in Enum]: { a: K, b: TypeMap[K] } }[Enum]
// type DiscrimUnion = { a: Enum.A; b: number;} | { a: Enum.B; b: string;} | 
//   { a: Enum.C; b: boolean;}
```

And then the implementation works the way you want:

```
function doSomethingDiscrimUnion(u: DiscrimUnion) {
  if (u.a === Enum.A) {
    let num: number = u.b;
  } else if (u.a === Enum.B) {
    let str: string = u.b;
  }
}
```

and has better guarantees about how you can call it:

```
doSomethingDiscrimUnion({a: Enum.A, b: 123}); // okay
doSomethingDiscrimUnion({a: getEnum(), b: "oops"}); // error! not a DiscimUnion
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Kz-pAVPL2WBJCDsBDgIK2CKZ-36ZpJUyRz85emDMYgTO52DnOksgiJsY2w3QyAgggU1H9goAIwAJgAzMR6k0WlYANaMJwZ5jIiUzXsGjbePe+LFIEZREpU1S1N+DQ+h0XTdK0Py0m2kG3mQQA)

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is honestly kind of sad, given that the usecase isn't even that complex, yet TypeScript can't properly handle it. I really hope they'll implement generic type narrowing someday. The discriminated union solution is the preferable one, since it offers 100% type-safety, which I want. But kind of sucks that I have to call the function with an object now...

Answer (score 3):

I may have found a solution using type predicates. 
In alternative to the classical way of doing type checking (a === Enum.A) we can define a function in which we pass both A and B and narrow the type of B with respect the value of A by using type predicates (basically the keyword **is**). Like so:

```
function isA(a: Enum, b: any): b is TypeMap[Enum.A] {
  return a === Enum.A
}

//function isB
//function isC

function doSomething<K extends Enum>(a: K, b: TypeMap[K]) {
  if (isA(a, b)) {
      let x: number = b; 
  }
}
```

By doing so we can let the compiler successfully narrow the type of B.

You can check this out at [this link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAou0G8BQVVQIIBoVoELbSgGEkBfJJASxABdgAnAMwEMBjYKAFQE8AHYALLNeUZIQDacSADp0AXQBcUeACMGBNJPjTciqAGca9agHMNqLTKJ6VAe1sAbYMxBkKjMCFY1KtkFEp9dAAKZiUpCEwoFSUXbgBKJRUA-S4+QWFLCFk5URx6YBowen9mKABeSthtdDIoCiQPLx8-KAATWwBlWwhCgAtTAB4AaShgAA86EDbUiIA+UKVhqJi0-iFecWG5eLzUSkYoYMCQ5hX43bFCKCcaKHGlVQYK6IBuetRyciQO7t6aAYgEzBCKyKIARnirx+XR6-VMIJqUQARH1gA4HLZkVCgA).

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know this was possible. This is quite powerful! It says b is now of Type "TypeMap[K] & number", which I guess is fine?

Comment: Yeah it should be fine I guess. It's basically the intersection type between (string | number | boolean) & number which is obviously the type "number"