# Is it possible to have multiple return types for a generic Typescript function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am currently designing a web server with Typescript and have hit a dead end. The target is to have an interface or something similar that lets any other developer without a deep knowledge of the rest of the system just come in, implement their own version of the parser and have it work with the rest of the system. Additionally, I would like to have the option to add more return types without modifying the original code.

Currently, I have the shape of the data defined and I am trying to wrap my head around the parser itself. The data looks like this:

```
export namespace CardData {
   export interface Base {
        type: string;
        source: Source;
    }

    export interface Graph {
        labels: string[];
        data: number[];
    }

    // Other definitions below
}
```

And the parser interface looks like this:

```
export interface Source {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    url: string;
    isReachable: boolean;
    type: string;
}

export interface ConnectorArgument {
    id: number;
    key: string;
    value: string;
}

export interface Parser {
    // Unrelated code

    // The type of T depends on args
    getSource: <T>(
        source: Source,
        args: ConnectorArgument[]
    ) => Promise<T>;
}
```

But if I implement getSource and try to return anything, I get:

`'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Graph'.`

I understand why Typescript refuses to let this work since the type of T is determined by the caller of the function but I have not been able to come up with a good alternative that would work.

I have looked at other questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199372/typescript-function-return-type-based-on-argument-without-overloading) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817922/typescript-return-type-depending-on-parameter) but none of them really fit my problem. Is this even possible to do in Typescript or am I better off using other languages?

**Edit 1:** I have added definitions for Source and ConnectorArgument.

Comment: Your code comment says `The type of T depends on args`. Could you clarify how, ideally showing a (perhaps simplified) definition of `Source` and `ConnectorArgument`? TypeScript generics often derive their types from arguments, but other approaches like overloading might be appropriate here too. The extra context would help.

Comment: Sure thing. They are just objects in a database and the array of ConnectorArgument serves as a list of arguments, that are used during the data retrieval from the source. For example type of the card data requested, time span, branches to be retrieved and so on. So basically there is a string that says what kind of T should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the string `type` property inside your `source` arg should determine the overall return type, there is a TypeScript paradigm that can handle this mapping. It's the same one used by `addEventListener` and its kin in TypeScript's DOM declarations, if you want to consult a broader example.

In your case, you'll need to create a map interface between `type` string values and the actual types that will be returned for them. The return type of `getSource` will then be a lookup from that map. Unfortunately, due to [some limitations in TypeScript described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61858881/16062123), there's an inelegant cast needed when returning each of the possible types. Here's how it all might look (with simpler structures for example purposes):

```
interface Widget { foo: number }
interface Sprocket { bar: number }

interface SourceTypeMap {
    'widget': Widget;
    'sprocket': Sprocket;
}

interface Source {
    type: keyof SourceTypeMap;
}

interface Parser {
    getSource: <T extends keyof SourceTypeMap>(
        source: Source & { type: T }
    ) => Promise<SourceTypeMap[T]>;
}

class ExampleParser implements Parser {
    async getSource<T extends keyof SourceTypeMap>(
        source: Source & { type: T }
    ): Promise<SourceTypeMap[T]> {
        return ((): SourceTypeMap[keyof SourceTypeMap] =>
        {
            switch (source.type) {
            case 'widget':
                return { foo: 42 };
            case 'sprocket':
                return { bar: 42 };
            }
            throw new TypeError(`unsupported type '${source.type}'`);
        }) () as SourceTypeMap[T];
    }
}

async function test() {
    const parser = new ExampleParser ();
    const widget = await parser.getSource({ type: 'widget' }); // infers Widget type
    console.log(widget); // { foo: 42 }
    const sprocket = await parser.getSource({ type: 'sprocket' }); // infers Sprocket type
    console.log(sprocket); // { bar: 42 }
}

test();
```

[Here's a runnable version on the TypeScript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#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-M-P4AoHnsHS+dHmt4WwuPCXuDWODAPBnkFoDNWoFjGJlkgoR0P0sZgh2QAB6eDwRAGBoB6Zx7FbZJJhfGZATNV5iCwMZ33sODELEH0KEDBdqlwvBIz8UQvx-P9TwfYCMVA8C1gjXwQgcWDXAQpDQFQkFVH4-wsP0HDj2IfDCOIxiBPIpDCGTai00XFgdz3IcWCAA)

Comment: Aw man, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I thought I was at least proficient with Typescript but I don't think I would be able to work towards something like this.