# Typescript: A type is not assignable to instance of generic type - both looks the same

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
export type Animal<T extends Kind> = T extends "cat"
  ? CatData<T>
  : DogData<"dog">

export type Kind = "cat" | "dog"

type CatData<T extends "cat"> = {
  kind: T
  someData: number[]
}
type DogData<T extends "dog"> = {
  kind: T
  someData: string[]
}

const fun = <T extends Kind>(kind: T): Animal<T> => {
  switch (kind) {
    case "cat":
      return {
        kind,
        someData: [33],
      }
    default:
      return {
        kind,
        someData: ["data"],
      }
  }
}
```

For above code I got two errors regarding both cases in switch statement. Both errors are the same:

```
 test.ts    24   7 error    2322   Type '{ kind: T; someData: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Animal<T>'. (lsp)
```

I don't understand why those types are not assignable to Animal. I'm probably missing something but they look like they are instances of generic Animal type with T provided by function's argument.

What's wrong with above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `fun`, you want to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) the type `T`, and thus `Animal<T>`, but you're actually just narrowing the type of the argument `kind`. Checking that `kind` equals, e.g., `"cat"` doesn't necessarily imply anything about other variables of type `T`, including the return value of the function. That is in part [a limitation in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61858881/16062123).

The idiom that you want here is a map of `Kind`s to `Animal` types using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). That will clean up the structuring of the types, but it doesn't address the limitation above. A wrapper inside the function, while not very elegant, can take care of that. Here's the whole thing:

```
interface KindMap {
  "cat": CatData
  "dog": DogData
}
export type Kind = keyof KindMap
export type Animal<T extends Kind> = KindMap[T]

type CatData = {
  kind: "cat"
  someData: number[]
}
type DogData = {
  kind: "dog"
  someData: string[]
}

const fun = <T extends Kind>(kind: T): Animal<T> => {
  return ((): KindMap[Kind] => {
    switch (kind) {
      case "cat":
        return {
          kind,
          someData: [33],
        }
      default:
        return {
          kind,
          someData: ["data"],
        }
    }
  }) () as Animal<T>;
}

console.log(fun("cat")) // {"kind":"cat","someData":[33]}
console.log(fun("dog")) // {"kind":"dog","someData":["data"]}
// console.log(fun("sphinx")) // Argument of type '"sphinx"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof KindMap'.(2345)
```

([TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#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-CBOHJVb5gNwQHAKsb5JxkLg4FA4IVIFAm4Z6m3dPpDOsTG2TZsAExkgAsAFZ9kQgA))